How do I change single bits in registers of external device if I can only write the whol register at once?
I'm using an ESP32 and C to talk to an external component via SPI.
This component can be configured via 255 24bit registers.
The problem is sometimes I just need to flip a single bit in a register and leave the rest (of the register) unchanged, but I can only write whole registers.
I see two possibilities for a solution, and both are unsatisfactory:

Keep track of registers in a uint32_t[255] or something like that. This seems wasteful, and error-prone, since it's duplicating information and could get out of sync.
Set the device to read mode (yes there's read and write mode), read the register, change it, set the device to write mode and write it back. This doubles or quadruples the amount of SPI transactions needed.

What's the preferred way of doing this, or is there a more elegant solution I am missing?

Are all registers used equally often? If not, then you could use hybrid model: cache most used ones, and use read-modify-write for lesser used ones.

No not all registers get used equally. But keeping separate implementations for different registers feels kinda hacky.

For slow connections, it's faster to keep external state.

If the device registers can't be changed except by you writing them, I don't see the first solution as being overly problematic unless you have limited RAM.

Unless you share relevant requirements, this asks for opinions, which is unfortunately off-topic. So please [edit] your question to add requirements on RAM usage, transaction performance, and what you else see fit, and of course the additional information of your former comments. To be able to answer, we also need relevant data of the device, like SPI speed and the detailed access protocol. It's best to summary these and link to its data sheet.

In most cases, a large proportion of registers are set once and never changed or not explicitly set at all (default value), and in many cases the whole register can be written without reference to the current value if it is not composed of bit-fields.  In some cases a register may change outside of the control of your program and in a subset of those cases writing those registers may have no effect on some or all bits (read-only bits).
So really there is no one-solution appropriate to all circumstances, and you would do well to implement all of:

unconditional write
read-modify-write
cache-modify-write

And use whichever is appropriate to the specific register and application requirements.
With cache-modify-write rather than caching the whole register file, you might do that on a per register basis. Given say:
typedef struct
{
    uint8_t adr ;
    uint8_t cache ;
    bool cached ;
} tCachedReg ;


uint8_t cachedWriteBits( tCachedReg* reg, uint8_t msk, uint8_t val )
{
    if( !reg->cached )
    {
        reg->cache = msk == 0xFF ? val : readReg( reg->adr ) ;
        reg->cached = true ;
    }
    reg.cache = (reg->cache & ~msk) | (val & msk) ;
    writeReg( reg->adr, reg->cache ) ;

    return reg->cache ;
}

you can then write code such as:
tCachedReg somereg = { 0xA5 } ;

// Clear MSB
cachedWriteBits( &somereg, 0x80, 0 ) ;

On the first write this will be a read-modify-write, subsequently it will use the cached value.  If the register is to be wholly initialised on first write, you can avoid the initial read by initialising the tCachedReg, e.g.:
tCachedReg somereg = { 0xA5, 0x55, true } ;

// Clear MSB
cachedWriteBits( &somereg, 0x80, 0 ) ;

Then on first write, the register will be written to 0x55 in this case.
It is quite flexible, but you do have to take care not to combine cache-modify-write with read-modify-write or unconditional write for the same register without also modifying the cache.  You could do that by passing the tCachedReg struct to all methods, allowing NULL for those registers you have no need to cache.  You could do the same for reads, where the read would initialise the cache if provided.

Well answered concerning the various approaches.

Thank you, this solution addresses all my concerns.

@ckafi note update, no need to read the current value when msk == 0xFF.
